# Wrap mdframed environment into a command

Tags: macros, environments, mdframed

I've created (copied) a simple environment in order to create a frame around a piece of text. The environment uses the `mdframes` environment in order to box the content and a simple macro `changemargin` that is used to add some white space at the left and at the right of the box.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

% mdframe: put a certain amount of text in a box
\usepackage[framemethod=default]{mdframed}
\usepackage{showexpl}
\mdfdefinestyle{exampledefault}{
    rightline=true,
    innerleftmargin=10,
    innerrightmargin=10,
    frametitlerule=true,
    frametitlerulecolor=black,
    frametitlebackgroundcolor=white,
    frametitlerulewidth=1pt,
}

% macro to change margins
\def\changemargin#1#2{\list{}{\rightmargin#2\leftmargin#1}\item[]}
\let\endchangemargin=\endlist

% custom environment
\newenvironment{Boxed}[1]
{
    \begin{changemargin}{2cm}{2cm} 
    \begin{mdframed}[style=exampledefault, frametitle={#1}]
}
{
    \end{mdframed}
    \end{changemargin}
}

\usepackage{lipsum} % add some text

\begin{document}
    \lipsum
    \begin{Boxed}{I'm the title}
        I'm the content. I've a nice frame around me.
    \end{Boxed}
\end{document}
```

This is the result. It works perfectly.
[image]

My question is, can I use my environment like a command?

```
\Boxed{title}{content}
```

Comment: @ChristianHupfer ok thank you. I'm adding it

Comment: I am correcting my previous statement (and deleted it) -- it is possible

Comment: thank you very much :) I'm trying it. Is the question ok?

Comment: Yes, much better, but do you really need the `changemargin` 'environment'?

Comment: Probably no. Without it the result is much nicer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is in fact possible to use a `mdframed` environment within a command if it is wrapped in an internal `BoxedInternal` environment.

I've improved the example with an optional argument to the `BoxedInternal` environment and `\Boxed` macro.

The question is whether such wrapper commands are useful in general.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[xcolor]{mdframed}

\def\changemargin#1#2{\list{}{\rightmargin#2\leftmargin#1}\item[]}
\let\endchangemargin=\endlist

\mdfdefinestyle{exampledefault}{backgroundcolor=yellow!10!white}

\newenvironment{BoxedInternal}[2][]
{%
  \begin{changemargin}{0cm}{0cm}%
    \begin{mdframed}[style=exampledefault, frametitle={#2},#1]
    }{%
    \end{mdframed}%
  \end{changemargin}%
}

\newcommand{\Boxed}[3][]{%
  \begin{BoxedInternal}[#1]{#2}
    #3
  \end{BoxedInternal}%
}

\begin{document}

\Boxed{Foo}{Foobar}


\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: It works perfectly

Comment: @Ignus: Happy TeXing then. And `tcolorbox` has such `\Boxed` commands out of the box (pun intended ;-), perhaps you can give it a try also

Comment: Can I ask you another thing? Why Boxed takes three arguments insted of two?

Comment: @Ignus: You can use it this way `\Boxed[backgroundcolor=green]{Title}{Content}`, the first argument with `[...]` is handed to the `mdframed` environment, so you could change the view etc. of the underlying box. If you never need this feature, just don't think about `[...]`, just always use it as `\Boxed[title]{content}` and all is fine